# How can I join collections in mongoDB using aggregate and specifiy a specific record froam one

Tags: mongodb, mern

I have a mern app and I am trying to join data from three collections (teamMembers, user, userStyles) but for a specific team.  Throught lots of searching I am able to get the data from all three collections, but I cannot figure out how to get them for a specific teamId.

My original query was:

```
const members = await TeamMember.find({ teamId: teamId }).populate("userId", "firstName lastName");
```

This gave me the information I wanted, but when I tried to add userStyle, the only way I could find to get it to work was to use aggregate.  This is what I have now:

```
const members = await TeamMember.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "userstyles",
        localField: "userId",
        foreignField: "userId",
        as: "userStyle",
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "userId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "userInfo",
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        "userStyle._id": 0,
        "userInfo._id": 0,
      },
    },
  ]);
```

This works, but how can I specifity the teamId to get the users and there styles from a specific team?

I tried:

```
const members = await TeamMember.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
          teamId: teamId,
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "userstyles",
        localField: "userId",
        foreignField: "userId",
        as: "userStyle",
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "userId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "userInfo",
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        "userSTyle._id": 0,
        "userInfo._id": 0,
      },
    },
  ]);
```

Here is exerpt for one user but it is giving me this information for every user and I only want the users from a specific team.

```
{
        "teamId": "65babd21304316d764ff8674",
        "userId": "65b677d92bbf3f6836b31da8",
        "role": "Manager",
        "createdAt": "2024-01-31T21:35:29.390Z",
        "updatedAt": "2024-01-31T21:35:29.390Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "userStyle": [
            {
                "_id": "65be39875b721171d3e2daeb",
                "styleName": "Judo",
                "rank": "Rokyudan",
                "promotionDate": null,
                "weightClass": "73kg",
                "division": "",
                "grip": "Righty",
                "favoriteTechnique": "Ippon seoi nage to the left",
                "userId": "65b677d92bbf3f6836b31da8",
                "createdAt": "2024-02-03T13:03:03.900Z",
                "updatedAt": "2024-02-03T13:03:03.900Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "65be548b5c42c1bad874b98b",
                "styleName": "Brazilian Jiu Jitsu",
                "rank": "Blue belt",
                "promotionDate": null,
                "weightClass": "180 lbs",
                "division": "Novice Men",
                "grip": "Righty",
                "favoriteTechnique": "Mount",
                "userId": "65b677d92bbf3f6836b31da8",
                "createdAt": "2024-02-03T14:58:19.475Z",
                "updatedAt": "2024-02-03T14:58:19.475Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "65be58415c42c1bad874b9e8",
                "styleName": "Wrestling",
                "rank": "No rank",
                "promotionDate": null,
                "weightClass": "155 lbs",
                "division": "Boys",
                "grip": "Righty",
                "favoriteTechnique": "Sup",
                "userId": "65b677d92bbf3f6836b31da8",
                "createdAt": "2024-02-03T15:14:09.735Z",
                "updatedAt": "2024-02-03T15:14:09.735Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "userInfo": [
            {
                "firstName": "Stephen",
                "lastName": "Moore",
                "city": "Denver",
                "state": "Colorado",
                "username": "stephenmoore",
                "isCoach": true,
                "isParent": true,
                "isAdmin": false,
                "verified": true,
                "tokens": [],
                "allowPublic": false,
                "createdAt": "2024-01-28T15:50:49.925Z",
                "updatedAt": "2024-02-03T04:49:47.628Z",
                "__v": 0,
                "athlete": "65b677da2bbf3f6836b31dac",
                "gender": "Male",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "teamId": "65babdeb629e336c335d310d",
        "userId": "65b677d92bbf3f6836b31da8",
        "role": "Manager",
        "createdAt": "2024-01-31T21:38:51.393Z",
        "updatedAt": "2024-01-31T21:38:51.393Z",
        "__v": 0,
        ...
        ...
    },
```

but doesn't return anything.

Is this possible with aggregate or is there anoter way I have to do it?

Comment: Can you post the sample json documents and the expected output?

Comment: In general your aggregation pipeline looks fine. Maybe a typo? Field and collection names are case-sensitive.

Comment: I added a sample of the output.  It's working but I can't figure out how to only get data from members of a specific team using teamId.

Comment: I am betting `teamId` is not set to what you expect.

Comment: But when I use const members = await TeamMember.find({ teamId: teamId }) I get the correct team and even the user if I use .populate("userId", "firstName lastName")

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti - techniqally you were right.  I didn't have to do this for the initial query, teamId: teamId worked but for the aggregate I had to use teamId: new ObjectId(teamId).